# dynamically add fields to form and access the values from php script

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am adding text fields to the form dynamically, but now I need to be able to store these values into a mysql database. I am able to do this if there are no dynamically created fields. Here is the code -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>  
        <title> Company Value form </title>
        <script language = "javascript">
            function addTextField(){
                var element = document.createElement("input");
                element.setAttribute("name", "i");
                element.setAttribute("value", "sample value");
                element.setAttribute("size", 30);

                var twitter = document.getElementById("twitterusernames");
                twitter.appendChild(element);

            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Enter the values </h1>
        <form method = "post" name = "config_form" action = "message.php">
            <table border = "1px" >
                <tr> <td>
                    <b> Twitter </b> <br/> <br/>
                    FeatureId: <input type = "text" name = "FeatureId"> <br/>
                    Image: <input type = "text" name = "Image"> <br/>
                    LabelEn: <input type = "text" name = "LabelEn"> <br/>
                    LabelFr: <input type = "text" name = "LabelFr"> <br/>
                    URL: <input type = "text" name = "URL"> <br/>
                    TwitterUserNames: <input type = "text" name = "TwitterUserName" size = "50">  
                    <input type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = "addTextField()"/>
                    <span id="twitterusernames">&nbsp;</span>
                    <br/>
                    Minimum Count: <input type = "text" name = "MinimumCount"> <br/>
                    Refresh Count: <input type = "text" name = "RefreshCount"> <br/>
                    EmptyMessage English: <input type = "text" name = "EmptyMessageEnglish"> <br/>
                    EmptyMessage French: <input type = "text" name = "EmptyMessageFrench"> <br/>
                    Widget: <input type = "text" name = "Widget"> <br/>
                    Email Share Text: <input type = "text" name = "EmailShareText"> <br/>
                </td> </tr>
            </table>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>


</html>
```

and the PHP code:

```
<?php   
    include 'database.php';

    $Twitter = array(
        'FeatureId' => $_POST["FeatureId"],
        'Image' => $_POST["Image"],
        'LabelEn' => $_POST["LabelEn"],
        'LabelFr' => $_POST["LabelFr"],
        'URL' => $_POST["URL"],
        'TwitterUserName' => $_POST["TwitterUserName"],
        'MinimumCount' => $_POST["MinimumCount"],
        'RefreshCount' => $_POST["RefreshCount"],
        'EmptyMessageEnglish' => $_POST["EmptyMessageEnglish"],
        'Widget' => $_POST["Widget"],
        'EmailShareText' => $_POST["EmailShareText"]
        );

    $crud = new database();
    $insert = $crud -> insert($Twitter);

    if ($insert) {
        echo "Success";
    }
    else {
        echo "Values were not inserted into the database";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Where are you actually referring to your dynamic fields in your PHP code?  And you should add the type to your new fields.

Comment: right now the dynamic fields are not there in the PHP code. That is the question, how do I go about adding those ?

Comment: refer to them by the name (i) that you used.

Comment: You haven't really fully described the use case.  How do these dynamically added fields map to fields in the database?  Are there an unpredictable number of dynamic fields? Do the dynamic field represent more rows to be inserted into the DB or simply more field data on the row to be inserted?

Comment: @CMKanode - Hmm, when I add the field and then look at the page source, I do not see those fields. So will I still be able to access those from PHP ?

Comment: Yes.  Often times when you add elements dynamically, they will not show in the page source.  One trick in FireFox that I've used was select everything, and then right-click and view selection source.  That would show you the newly inserted elements.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've used all of it to finally solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this `element.setAttribute("name", "i[]");`

Then in your php handler

```
        $Twitter = array(
        'FeatureId' => $_POST["FeatureId"],
        'Image' => $_POST["Image"],
        'LabelEn' => $_POST["LabelEn"],
        'LabelFr' => $_POST["LabelFr"],
        'URL' => $_POST["URL"],
        'TwitterUserName' => $_POST["TwitterUserName"],
        'MinimumCount' => $_POST["MinimumCount"],
        'RefreshCount' => $_POST["RefreshCount"],
        'EmptyMessageEnglish' => $_POST["EmptyMessageEnglish"],
        'Widget' => $_POST["Widget"],
        'EmailShareText' => $_POST["EmailShareText"],
        'extraFields' => serialize( $_POST["i"] ) // Extra fields
        );

        $crud = new database();
        $insert = $crud -> insert($Twitter);

        if ($insert) {
        echo "Success";
        }
        else {
        echo "Values were not inserted into the database";
        }

        ?>
```

to display the data. let's assume that you already have the `$extraFields`

```
<?php
$extraFields = unserialize( $extraFields );

 foreach($extraFields as $extra ):
?>
<input type="text" name="i[]" value="<?php echo $extra; ?> ">
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the dynamic elements names ending in `[]`:

```
element.setAttribute("name", "i[]");
```

Then PHP will fill `$_POST['i']` with an array of all the values.

Answer (score 2):

According to your script I got idea like you are adding text box after clicking button. So when you are adding multiple textbox you need to make your textbox field name as a array i.e

```
<input type="text" name="i[]" value="sample data" />
<input type="text" name="i[]" value="sample data" />
<input type="text" name="i[]" value="sample data" />
```

**Modify your addTextField() function**

```
function addTextField(){
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.setAttribute("name", "i[]");
            element.setAttribute("value", "sample value");
            element.setAttribute("size", 30);

            var twitter = document.getElementById("twitterusernames");
            twitter.appendChild(element);

        }
```

And in **message.php** file you can get value through $_POST[i] in array format.

Answer (score 0):

If added fields contain only secondary data, I'd just add another column with text type and just dump there JSON-encoded values of these fields in one chunk.

Comment: True, I have an idea of how to go about with the MySQL portion of the code. But how do I access the form values from the PHP script using $_POST

Comment: @AshishAgarwal you can keep needed parameters in separate array (say, `$primary = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];`), use it to fill data (`foreach ($primary as $p) { if (isset($_POST[$p])) {$Twitter[$p] = $_POST[$p];}}`) and then use [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) to get secondary data using $primary and $_POST.